# BootStrap Angular Dynamic Accordion is not working

Tags: angularjs

```js
var myApp = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
    myApp.directive('customCollapse', function () {
        return {
            require: '?ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div class="panel-group" id="{{panelId}}">\
                       <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat-start="item in ngModel">\
                           <div class="panel-heading">\
                               <h4 class="panel-title">\
                                        <a ng-click="toggleCollapsedStates($index)" href="#{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</a>\
                               </h4>\
                           </div>\
                                        <div id="{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}" data-parent="#{{panelId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">\
                               <div class="panel-body">{{item.content}}</div>\
                           </div>\
                       </div>\
                       <div ng-repeat-end></div>\
                   </div>',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.panelBaseId = attrs.collapsePanelBodyId;
                scope.panelId = attrs.collapsePanelId;

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function (value, key) {
                        if (value.collapsed) {
                            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + key).collapse('show');
                        }
                    });
                });

                scope.toggleCollapsedStates = function (ind) {
                    angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function (value, key) {
                        if (key == ind) {
                            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = !scope.ngModel[key].collapsed;
                            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + ind).collapse('toggle');
                        }
                        else
                            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    });

    myApp.controller('CustomDirectivesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.collapseData = [
        {
            title: "Collapse Group Item Title 1",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            collapsed: true
        },
        {
            title: "Collapse Group Item Title 2",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            collapsed: false
        },
        {
            title: "Collapse Group Item Title 2",
            content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            collapsed: false
        }
    ];
    }]);
```

```html
<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app="customDirectives">
    <div ng-controller="CustomDirectivesController">       
        <div custom-collapse ng-model="collapseData" collapse-panel-id="collapse-panel" collapse-panel-body-id="collapse-panel-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to Angular JS. I wnat an nested accordion control which is genertaed dynamically. However, i was trying one sample code. It is throwing collapse function is not an object or property....undefined. 
$("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + key).collapse('show');

Above line is throwing error. inside document.ready. am i missing any reference??? Thanks.
 [image]

Comment: And the thrown error is ... ?

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'collapse'

Comment: I have tried your code, seem working. You can change my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/h1tu2oyv/) for your situation

Comment: Thanks @themyth92 , I skipped this approach. I'm using bootstrap accordion. which is working for me